# Does subduing enemies give the same experience as killing them?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

In XCOM: Chimera Squad, does subduing enemies give the same experience as killing them?

I've been subduing a lot of enemies for several reasons (sometimes it's tactically more reliable, for Verge's powers, and for roleplay), but I'm worried that I'm disadvantaging my team by doing so. Actually, is there even the same XP system as in previous games? The UI doesn't explicitly say so, and promotions could just be given after a certain number of missions..?

Answer (score 2):

XCOM: Chimera Squad, to the best of my knowledge, grants XP based on mission taken. There is no additional XP for taking down an opponent, lethally or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no differentiation XP-wise if an enemy was killed or subdued, it has the only effect on +20% chance to get 20 Intel after the mission.